# Unable to obtain dns hostname of active directory domain controller with ntdsa object name while AD Authentication

Tags: active-directory

showing "**Unable to obtain dns hostname of active directory domain controller with ntdsa object name**" msg while authentication with Active Directory on Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Please refer this document it may help you : https://pradeepg81.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/unable-to-obtain-dns-hostname-of-active-directory-domain-controller-with-ntdsa-object-name/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where your DNS is routing you.

Could be as simple as getting your DNS to talk to your server properly / take you to another DC in priority.

Since you just enter "the AD" here... You need to prioties to one DC since you are using more than one DC.

[image]

You can also refer this [**document1**](https://pradeepg81.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/unable-to-obtain-dns-hostname-of-active-directory-domain-controller-with-ntdsa-object-name/) and [***Document2***](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4c6dd616-f61d-454a-8fe8-0d8f67e35ebb/unable-to-obtain-dns-hostname-of-active-directory-domain-controller-with-ntdsa-object?forum=winserverDS) for troubleshooting your issue.